# "when it will X" - what does it mean?

Tags: tense, subjunctives

> They earn our trust by telling us the truth about little things, but then they betray us when it **will** damage us the most. [Source](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/macbeth/page_20.html)

Is this will grammatical?
This is about the future ...so I thought it couldn't be used with when...i mean not within the when clause...

Comment: Why do you think "when" can't be used with the future?

Comment: "When" and the future "will" can be used in the same clause.  Yes, usually we say things like "I will see him **when he arrives**", but if you want to emphasize the "future-ness", it is also acceptable to say "I will see him in two years, **when he will be five years old**."

Answer (score 2):

**When** simply means that you are referring to a particular time in the same way that **where** refers to a particular place. Whether the time is in the past, present, or future does not matter.

Examples:

> That was a time when things were better.
>
> This is the moment when I start to regret my decision.
>
> Tomorrow is the day when my brother will come to visit.